# Data pushed to next view is inconsistent

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I'm having troubles pushing data to the next view in SwiftUI. The first data pushed is correct for one annotation , but all the others either push nothing or the wrong data :-(. Looks like the declaration isn't made in the right place, but cannot find out where.

Here's my MapView :

```
import MapKit
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation

struct MapViewJS: View {

  @State private var locations: [Location] = []
  private var viewModel: MapViewModel = MapViewModel()
    
  
    @State private var isAnnotationTapped = false
    @State var selected: Location?
    @State private var isDetailViewPresented = false
    @State private var valueToPass = "Test value"
  
  @State private var coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 50.724286, longitude: 0.181787), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 2.5, longitudeDelta: 2.5))

  var body: some View {
      
    Map(coordinateRegion: viewModel.binding,annotationItems: locations) { location in
      MapAnnotation(
        coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(
          latitude: location.latitude,
          longitude: location.longitude
        )
      ) {
          VStack {
               Text("")
               Image(systemName: "location.north.line")
                  .font(.system(size: 20))
                  .foregroundColor(.indigo)
                  .scaledToFit()
                  .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                  .frame(width: 100, height: 25)
                  .clipShape(Circle())
                  .overlay(
                      Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 25/10))
                  .shadow(radius: 10)
                  .onTapGesture {
                      if let currentSelected = selected, currentSelected == location {
                          selected = nil
                      } else {
                          selected = location
                      }
                  }
              
              Button(action: {
                                  isDetailViewPresented.toggle()
                            }) {
                                Text("\(location.name)  \n  \(location.latitude)")
                                
                            }
                            .sheet(isPresented: $isDetailViewPresented) {
                                DetailView(passedValue: Binding(
                                    get: {
                                        location.name
                                    },
                                    set: { passedValue in
                                        isDetailViewPresented = false
                                    }
                                ))
                            }

            .opacity(location.ident == selected?.ident ? 1 : 0)
            } //vstack
      }
    }
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    .onAppear(perform: {
        viewModel.checkIfLocationIsEnabled();readFile()
                })
    }

   private func readFile() {
    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "events", withExtension: "json"),
       let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
      let decoder = JSONDecoder()
      if let jsonData = try? decoder.decode(JSONData.self, from: data) {
        self.locations = jsonData.locations
      }
    }
  }
    
    
}

struct DetailView: View {
    //should be webview
    @Binding var passedValue: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Passed Value: \(passedValue)")
            
       }
    }
}

struct JSONData: Decodable {
  let locations: [Location]
}

struct Location: Decodable, Identifiable, Equatable {
  let id: Int
  let name: String
  let latitude: Double
  let longitude: Double
  let ident = UUID()
}

final class MapViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
    
    @Published var mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 50.724286, longitude: 0.181787), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 2.5, longitudeDelta: 2.5))
    
    var binding: Binding<MKCoordinateRegion> {
        Binding {
            self.mapRegion
        } set: { newRegion in
            self.mapRegion = newRegion
        }
    }
    
    
    func checkIfLocationIsEnabled() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
                    self.locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
                    self.locationManager?.delegate = self
                }
            } else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("Location services are off_checkIfLocationIsEnabled")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        switch manager.authorizationStatus {
        case .notDetermined:
            manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        case .restricted:
            print("Location is restricted_locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization")
        case .denied:
            print("Location permission denied_locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization")
        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
            checkLocationAuthorization()
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    
    private func checkLocationAuthorization() {
        guard let location = locationManager else {
            return
        }
        
        switch location.authorizationStatus {
        case .notDetermined:
            print("Location authorization_checkLocationAuthorization")
        case .restricted:
            print("Location is restricted_checkLocationAuthorization")
        case .denied:
            print("Location permission denied_checkLocationAuthorization")
        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let location = location.location {
                    self.mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location.coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2))
                }
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}


struct MapViewJS_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
      MapViewJS()
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should look at the Apple SwiftUI tutorials. That Binding variable doesn’t make sense. Also you should use sheet(item:) but there are many fundamental errors with your code.